# Calling cloud function admin.auth().createUser() from android does not work

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call a Google cloud function from an Android app that does not work (First call just after deployment works 90 % of the times but subsequent calls fails, nothing is displayed on firebase log console either).

```
public Task<String> myCloudFunction() {

    return FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
            .getHttpsCallable("createUser")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith(task -> {
                String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                return result;
            });

}
```

Endpoint in Functions Dashboard 
https://us-central1-xyz:555.cloudfunctions.net/createUser

This is how I call it.

```
public void callCloudFunction() {

    createFirebaseUserAccount.myCloudFunction()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Exception e = task.getException();
                        if (e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                            FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                            FirebaseFunctionsException.Code code = ffe.getCode();
                            Object details = ffe.getDetails();
                        } else {
                            Timber.d(task.getResult());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Here is the cloud function:
$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is pointing to service_key.json file which contains the private key.

```
admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
databaseURL: "https://XYZ.firebaseio.com"
});
exports.createUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
 const callerEmail = data.email;
 const callerPassword = data.password;
 const callerDisplayName = data.displayName;
 return admin.auth().createUser({ 
    email: callerEmail,
    emailVerified: false,
    password: callerPassword,
    displayName: callerDisplayName,
    disabled: false
   }).then(userRecord => {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
        return userRecord.uid;

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error creating new user ", error);
        return error;
    });
  });
```

Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code of the Cloud Function, and what you are doing with curl to invoke it.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks! I changed my cloud function to a background trigger instead of a http trigger and post more details.

Comment: FYI: A callable function isn't considered a "background" function.  It directly invoked just like an HTTP function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning a promise from the the function that contains the data to send to the client.  Actually, you're not passing anything at all.  You should instead return the promise chain from your async work:

```
return admin.auth().createUser({ 
    email: callerEmail,
    emailVerified: false,
    password: callerPassword,
    displayName: callerDisplayName,
    disabled: false
   }).then(userRecord => {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
        return userRecord.uid;

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error creating new user ", error);
        return error;
    });
```

Note the new `return` before the whole thing.  You should definitely take some time to learn about how JavaScript promises work in order to make effective use of Cloud Functions, and they will not work correctly without observing their rules and conventions.

Comment: problem solved! I was calling the cloud function from test class and it didn't work. But it works if I call it from postman or Activity.